# Dart is null check on List entry throws range error

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I have initialised an otherwise empty list and want to check if that entry is true or null. Since I can't practically populate every entry first with `false`, I need to check if it is null or true.

```
List<bool> check = List<bool>();
```

Whether I use:

```
(check[index]) ? dothis : dothat;
```

or:

```
(check[index] != null) ? dothis : dothat;
```

they both throw a range error. Since I can't initialise it like

```
List<bool> check = [false,false,false,false,false forever and ever];
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? You cannot access an index of a list which isn't there. Maybe use a set instead? `Set<int> chek = {}; ... check.contains(index) ? dothis : dothat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since I can't initialise it like
>
> `List<bool> check = [false,false,false,false,false forever and ever];`

It sounds to me like you want a *sparsely* populated `List`.  If so, just use a `Map<int, T>` instead of `List<T>`.  Then `check[index]` will return `null` if the item hasn't been added yet:

```dart
var check = <int, bool>{};
...
(check[index] ?? false) ? dothis : dothat;
```

In the case of `bool`, it'd be even better to use a `Set<int>` and just check for presence instead of maintaining a separate `bool` value:

```dart
var checked = <int>{};
...
checked.contains(index) ? dothis : dothat;
```

Comment: Yes the best answer is to use `checked.contains(index) ? dothis : dothat;` with a simple list of integers. That's what I did in the end. Bool is not the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the index exists, before getting the value.

```dart
List<bool> check = List<bool>();

if(index <= (check.length - 1)) {
  (check[index]) ? dothis : dothat;
}


OR

(index < check.length) 
                       ? (check[index]) ? Colors.blue : Colors.red
                       // return default color
                       :  Colors.white
```

Something like this should work!

Comment: But since it's Flutter it won't actually let me use `if` in this place. It's a paramater for colours in a widget. That's why I was using a ternary operator.

Comment: Oh man, I was just waiting for one of those super long ternary operators. Yeah of course that would work. I don't see why Dart doesn't have something like `firstOrNull`.

Comment: This actually doesn't work. If I set any value to true then it throws the range error again. It only works if the List is empty.

Comment: This won't work at all because if for example index entry 6 is true, then the length is 1 but the value at 0 is false so it will still throw a range error.

Comment: Try `check[5] = true;` it will throw the same range error since the length is 1 but the first entry is empty.

Answer (score 0):

To make life less painful:

```
extension ListExt<T> on List<T> {
  T? getOrNull(int index) {
    return index < length && index >= 0 ? this[index] : null;
  }

  T? nextOrNull(int index) => getOrNull(index + 1);

  T? prevOrNull(int index) => getOrNull(index - 1);
}
```

Then you can do:

```
[1, 2].getOrNull(0) // ==> 1
[1, 2].getOrNull(1) // ==> 2
[1, 2].getOrNull(2) // ==> null
[1, 2].getOrNull(-1) // ==> null

[1, 2].nextOrNull(0) // => 2
[1, 2].nextOrNull(1) // => null
[1, 2].nextOrNull(10) // => null

[1, 2].prevOrNull(0) // => null
[1, 2].prevOrNull(1) // => 1
[1, 2].prevOrNull(10) // => null
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List<bool> check = [];

if (check.length > index) {
  // you are safe to perform anything like check[index]
}
```

Update:

```
color: check.length > index ? (check[index] ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey) : Colors.white
```

Update2:

Not sure why you said it's not working, I am giving you a `build()` method, you can try to comment out the other code, and see it working.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var check = [true];
  int index = 5;

  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      color: check.length > index ? (check[index] ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey) : Colors.white,
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: But since it's Flutter it won't actually let me use `if` in this place. It's a paramater for colours in a widget. That's why I was using a ternary operator. Is there no null aware check?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get that, can you show the code where you want to use it?

Comment: It's like this `colour: (check[index]) ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey;` so you can't use `if` there.

Comment: This actually doesn't work. If I set any value to true then it throws the range error again. It only works if the List is empty.

Comment: This won't work at all because if for example index entry 6 is true, then the length is 1 but the value at 0 is false so it will still throw a range error. It only works if the List is empty.

Comment: But if you do `check[5] = true;` it throws a range error.

Comment: Did you try it like I said? `check = [true, false];` does not throw an error like you say, but `check[5] = true;` does. You are adding valid entries from 0 upwards when you do it like this `check = [true, false];` so there will be no error for the entire length of the array. But if you individually make entry 5 to true, then the entries before it are empty, that's why it throws an error.

Comment: The code is the same as yours but with `check[5] = true;`.

Comment: Are you 100% sure it works and do you have a working example? Please read my explanation above of why it doesn't work like that. My code is identical to yours but with `check[5] = true;` You have not updated your code with `check[5] = true;`.